# How to get btrfs to allocate space on new device?

Tags: btrfs

I have a btrfs filesystem for which the output of `btrfs fi usage /mnt` is:

```
Overall:
    Device size:          60.00GiB
    Device allocated:         40.00GiB
    Device unallocated:       20.00GiB
    Device missing:          0.00B
    Used:             38.03GiB
    Free (estimated):         10.00GiB  (min: 10.00GiB)
    Data ratio:               2.00
    Metadata ratio:           2.00
    Global reserve:       22.00MiB  (used: 0.00B)

Data,RAID1: Size:18.99GiB, Used:18.99GiB
   /dev/sdb   18.99GiB
   /dev/sdc   18.99GiB

Metadata,RAID1: Size:1.00GiB, Used:22.11MiB
   /dev/sdb    1.00GiB
   /dev/sdc    1.00GiB

System,RAID1: Size:8.00MiB, Used:16.00KiB
   /dev/sdb    8.00MiB
   /dev/sdc    8.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sdb    1.00MiB
   /dev/sdc    1.00MiB
   /dev/sdd   20.00GiB
```

As you can see, all allocated data chunks are completely full. `btrfs balance start /mnt` fails with:

```
ERROR: error during balancing '/mnt': No space left on device
There may be more info in syslog - try dmesg | tail
```

This is *not* a duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174446/btrfs-error-error-during-balancing-no-space-left-on-device), which is about metadata chunks being full. My question is how do I get btrfs to allocate some chunks on `/dev/sdd`

Comment: There is a RAID1 (mirror) defined with the disks sda and sdc. To use the space on sdd, you'ld have to convert to some other RAID level (RAID5, e.g.). See https://superuser.com/questions/901067/btrfs-convert-from-raid1-to-raid5.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a filesystem which is using the raid1 profile, which means you'll need to add a fourth device temporarily so that BTRFS can allocate new chunks.

Each profile has a minimum number of devices needed to allocate a chunk, and if there aren't that many devices with free space, you can't allocate a new chunk.  For raid1 and raid0, the minimum is 2, for raid10 it's 4, and for raid5 and raid6 it's 3 and 4 respectively.  The quick option if you've got lots of RAM and a reliable power supply is to temporarily add a 2-4 GB ramdisk to the filesystem, run a full balance, then remove the ramdisk from the filesystem.  A USB flash drive works too, but you may have reliability issues with that.

Alternatively, you *might* be able to get this working without needing to add another device if you start a balance with `-mconvert=single, -dconvert=single, -f`, let that run for a while, then kill it and rerun the balance with `-mconvert=raid1 -dconvert=raid1`, but that will mean some of your data will temporarily be at risk.