# How do you create block RAM Disks on demand?

Tags: linux, ramdisk

I learned that I can do `modprobe brd rd_nr=1 rd_size=4585760 max_part=1` if I want to create a ram block device at `/dev/ram0` but lets say I want to flush the device (to free the ram), then delete it and create another. How would I do this running `modprobe brd rd_nr=1 rd_size=4585760 max_part=1` again doesn't seem to create another ram device in `/dev`

Recreate steps:

1) create disk: `modprobe brd rd_nr=1 rd_size=4585760 max_part=1`

2) use the ram disk for some arbitrary task: ex: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ram0 count=1000`

3) free up the memory `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/ram0`

4) delete device file: `rm /dev/ram0`

5) try to create another one: `modprobe brd rd_nr=1 rd_size=4585760 max_part=1`

6) `ls /dev/ram*` gives me an error

I know that I can change the `rd_nr` to be whatever number I desire but I want to be able to create these on the fly.

Edit: I don't want to create a tmpfs, my use case requires a block device

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not delete `/dev/ram0` yourself. It will be deleted when you do `sudo rmmod brd`, which frees the space and removes the module.
You can then start again from `modprobe`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with /dev/ram but you can do something similar with tmpfs and loop devices:

```
mkdir /ramdisks
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /ramdisks
dd if=/dev/zero of=/ramdisks/disk0 bs=1M count=100
losetup /dev/loop0 /ramdisks/disk0
mke2fs /dev/loop0
...
losetup -d /dev/loop0
rm /ramdisks/disk0
```