# How to create a file-system in RAM? (a virtual disk-drive)

Tags: tmpfs, ramdisk

I'm aware of `tmpfs` and what I really need is a disk partition resides on RAM where I could format it with BTRFS.

How can I create a raw device on RAM and format it with any regular filesystem?

Or is only chance creating a raw file on `tmpfs`, formatting it with a filesystem and mounting through a loop device ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433720/65781)).

```
mkdir /ramdisks
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /ramdisks
dd if=/dev/zero of=/ramdisks/disk0 bs=1M count=100
losetup /dev/loop0 /ramdisks/disk0
mke2fs /dev/loop0
...
losetup -d /dev/loop0
rm /ramdisks/disk0
```

## Use Case

I'm using BTRFS for a number of reasons. My current attempt is to use Overlayfs as rootfs (just like [Slax does with Aufs](https://www.slax.org/internals.php)) and I want the underlying directory structure be BTRFS.

Slax uses the following trick: While the system is booting,

1. instead of actual `switch_root` operation that the normal installations usually do, Slax creates a transient folder and
2. mounts it as `tmpfs` (puts it on the RAM),
3. `switch_root` to it as if it were the actual filesystem.
4. Then it does some Kung-Fu: Mounts its "modules" (the squashfs files) to somewhere (say `/modules`)
5. Mounts all folders under `/modules/` to `/union` along with a writable `changes` folder
6. `pivot_root` to the `/union` folder.

What I want is mimicking that, which doesn't require what I asked so far, except: I want to place the `changes` folder on the RAM with the support of BTRFS goods:

1. Support snapshotting,
2. Support `btrfs send | btrfs receive`
3. Possibly BTRFS RAID-1

Comment: I am not sure if the `/dev/ramX`-type interface is still around; you may want to try instructions found [here](https://stackpointer.io/unix/linux-create-ram-disk-filesystem/438/) and then create a file system there, as mentioned [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/blockdev/ramdisk.txt).

Comment: Can you add some detail on **why** you want it in RAM? I think this may be an XY problem. It may not improve your performance, compared with using a file, withing an existing file-system.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Why RAM? (Lack of backing store?, expected performance increase?, other? )

Comment: There are couple of reasons. First, a NAND storage has limited number of write operations. I'm planning to make it last longer by using RAM for heavy operations (like dist-upgrade, etc) and "flush" the data to the permanent storage at periodic cycles and/or if operation succeeds. Secondly, I might keep the changes on the remote and patch the rootfs on boot with a minimum amount of data transferred. When I need to create an LXC container based on current rootfs which would be only saved if it succeeds somehow, it would be way efficient to create it on the RAM.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor  this doesnt matter. The question is clear and reasonable. Please answer the question as asked.

Comment: @Lothar who knows if it matters? Not me, only the OP can know and they seem to have lost interest.